# Breaking jQuery Loops

Tags: jquery, validation

This should be so simple, but I'm clearly missing something massively obvious here.

The following code should check input for either content or if it has a class and run function `error()`. This seems to be true and false and the same time, which is very confusing!

Any ideas what I am missing in the loop? I would have expected the `return false;` to stop the function, but it does not.

```
function error() {
    jQuery("#overlay,#required").fadeIn();
    jQuery(this).addClass("error");
}

// Step 1

jQuery("#step-1-next").click(function(){

    jQuery('#step-1 .b-left input[name=name], #step-1 .b-left input[name=email], #step-1 .b-left input[name=tel], #step-1 .b-left input[name=company]').each(function() {

        if (jQuery(this).val() == '' || jQuery(this).hasClass("error")) {

            error();
            return false;   

        } else {

            // continue

        }

    });

});
```

Comment: `I would have expected the return false; to stop the function, but it does not` How do you debug it???

Comment: What does "seems to be true and false and the same time" mean? What happens when you click the button and what did you expect to happen instead?

Comment: _`I would have expected the return false; to stop the function`_......No! it stops there as `error();` function doesn't know what `jQuery(this)` is.

Answer (score 0):

Here is strange place in the code, that you need to review maybe

```
if (jQuery(this).val() == '' || jQuery(this).hasClass("error")) { // true if element has a class error

 error(); // it already has class error, but method sets it again. If possible, reflow code
....
```

And one thing yet: You can inspect whether yes or not loop stopped at the right moment. Just add tracing `console.log` line, like:

```
 error();
 console.log('Bad input with name ' + $(this).attr('name'));
 return false;
```